# How to trace TempData in an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, trace, tempdata

I know we can trace Session data in ASP.NET application by enabling trace in config, and accessing "trace.axd" page in running session.
Now I want to trace TempData in my ASP.NET MVC application, and I tried out "trace.axd" but "Session State" section is showing empty, though there are objects in the session. I believe TempData is using Session in its underlying architecture so it should be shown in trace.axd, but as its not being shown, how do we trace tempdata?

Comment: TempData loses its value once you access it, so you might not be able to trace it the way you think you can.

Comment: I use TempData.Keep everytime I read them.. so in theory Session should be retained, and I can read the same TempData again and again at various places in my application.

Comment: Consider using log4net or System.Diagnostics for trace to what ever your preferred trace destination is, e.g. file, console (after attaching a console to the dev server process), etc.